# Aws Elastic Bean Stalk and allowing IP's

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dialogflow-es, ip-restrictions

I have an instance with Elastic Bean stalk and it connects with a dialogflow account . The only traffic that comes to elastic server is from dialogflow server's which are owned by google. I would like to restrict access to the elastic servers only from dialogflow.

Dialogflow can access elastic server using different IP's. Is there any way I could do that?

Thanks

Lynn

Comment: Elastic server = Instance deployed by Elastibeanstalk?

Comment: yes.. an Instance deployed via elasticbean stalk.